# Model is lost when passing model to view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller method that prepares a view model and passes it into a view:

```
public function Method()
{
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->Items = // get items from repository
    $viewModel->DropdownViewModel = new DropdownViewModel();
    View::make( "View/name", array( "Model" => $viewModel );
}
```

The view looks like this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Blah">Blah</label>
        <?=App::make( "BlahController" )->DropdownList( $Model->DropdownViewModel )?>
    </div>
```

At this point if i put a `print_r` before the App::make line, i see a nice result from my database. Perfect so far.

Now i go into my BlahController method:

```
public function DropdownList( DropdownViewModel $viewModel )
{
    return View::make( "Blah/_DropdownList", array( "Model" => $viewModel ) );
}
```

At this point if i `print_r` on the $viewModel.. It's still all in tact, and looking schmexy

The view looks like this:

```
<select name="Blah">
     <?php   GeneralHelper::PrintExt($Model); exit(); ?>
</select>
```

Now if i `print_r` in here, nothing comes out of here?

Any ideas where i might be going wrong?

- I have tried cloning the model just incase the passing of the models is going weird.
- I have tried renaming the variable for the view to "Poop" rather than "Model"

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, oh dear...

The print_r is happening inside a select box... OFCOURSE i can't see it, it's being hidden under the select element.

If i view source, i see it.

Oh dear oh dear.